# Replace words in word with vb

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I need to replace the word `<t>` with `Test` in the word.doc and change font color to red. I need help with the font color changing red

```
WordDoc.Content.Find.Execute(FindText:="<t>", ReplaceWith:="Test" Replace:=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
```

Comment: Won't this replace all `t` **letters**? I didn't think there was anything in `Content.Find()` to limit you to word boundaries.

Comment: You might use docx.dll at https://github.com/xceedsoftware/docx .

Comment: yes this would replace all the t letters with test in the word template

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The angeled brackets in the Find term mean beginning and end of Word. Take a look at the list of Special characters in Word's advanced Find dialog box.

Comment: @whatsup1234 Go into Word as a user, enter some test content into the document and press Ctrl+H to open the dialog box. Click the "More" button. Enter your search term in the Find box then click in the Replace with box. Now use the FORMAT button and select Font. Specify the font colour you want to use to replace. Test. When you've got it working, record a macro to get the syntax you need.

Answer (score 0):

The angled brackets in the Find term only mean beginning and end of a word when using 'MatchWildcards:=True'; that's not in the posted code.